# Google maps - get all markers inside a given radius

Tags: ios, api, google-maps, maps

I'm working on an iOS application and I want it to display all markers inside a given radius.

I'm using GMSGeometryDistance to calculate all marker distances and returning the ones that are in my given radius.

The current location changes on high frequency. That means I need to calculate this every time the location is changed and it will impair app performance.

Is there any function to calculate it every given distance that the user moved?

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>
I get all the markers with in the given radius by using below code.Please check it once.Hope it will help to you. </p>
<p>

<table>
<tr>
`CLLocationDistance dist = 800; // required radius in meters.
</tr>
<tr>
CLLocation *closestLocation;
</tr>
<tr>
// finalArr(NsMutableArray) stores coordinates fetching from database
</tr>
<tr>
for (CLLocation *location in finalArr) {
</tr>
<tr>
CLLocationDistance distance = [currentLoc  distanceFromLocation:location];
</tr>
<tr>
        if (distance < dist) {
</tr>
<tr>
closestLocation = location;
</tr>
<tr>
[closeLatArr addObject:@(closestLocation.coordinate.latitude)];
</tr>
<tr>
[closeLongArr addObject:@(closestLocation.coordinate.longitude)];
</tr>
<tr>
}
</tr>
<tr>
for (int i=0; i<[closeLatArr count]; i++) {

        GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[closeLatArr objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue], [[closeLongArr objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue]);

        //   marker.title = [locArr objectAtIndex:i];
        marker.map = mapView;
        //NSLog(@"closest loc are %@",locArr);

    }`
</tr>
</table>
</p>
```